# Check camera calibration efficiency, with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I am working on my sterio camera calibration using OpenCV. I have been following [this tutorial](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut10.html) and i have reached some good result. But the question is, how can check that my work is good enough to calibrate my camera?

You can see, the first picture is a screenshot of original camera stream and the second one is screenshot of the undistorted one.

[image: First picture]
[image: Second picture]

Answer (score 2):

You can print out a checkerboard pattern and photograph it straight-on, then undistort it and measure how straight and parallel the lines are, and compare the area of each checkerboard square.

Comment: thanks, but how can i measure this? I made the procedure of calibration using checkerboard of course

Comment: i changed the pictures by chessboard ones

Comment: You can do a simple edge-detection, fit a bunch of regression lines vertically and horizontally.  For straightness, compare the distribution of edge pixels above and below each line.  For paralellism you just compute the distribution of angles.  For distribution of areas, you can intersect pairs of vertical and horizontal lines and compute the area of each grid square.  If you then graph these three criteria by grid position, you should expect the distribution to be flat.

Comment: can you explain more to me plz?

Comment: Do you know anything about statistics?  That would be a good start.  I am suggesting that you devise a bunch of statistical criteria to demonstrate to satisfy yourself that various important elements of a normalised camera projection (straight lines and uniform spacing) are actually within acceptable levels.

Comment: I don't know anything about statistics.

Comment: Maybe it's time to start learning.  Computer vision is about 30% programming and 70% statistics.

Comment: Thank you vey much, do you have any online tutorial for beginners?